# How to copy text to the client's clipboard using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser, clipboard, copy-paste

The workflow is simple:

1. You click inside a textarea.
2. The text is copied to the client's clipboard.
3. Display notice to the user.

How do you do it?

Comment: From what I understand, you can not access the clipboard without user action. The javascript clipboard functionality has been disabled in most current browsers as it is a possible security risk. You can use some of the dynamic flash overlay type stuff like zeroclipboard but can be kinda complicated and not always stable. I developed a flash element that you might want to look at http://text2clipboard.com, sorry about the plug but it works and I included helpful relevant info.

Answer (score 33):

Copying to the clipboard is a tricky task to do in Javascript in terms of browser compatibility. The best way to do it is using a small flash. It will work on every browser. You can check it in [this article](http://wayback.archive.org/web/20091219184623/http://beckelman.net/demos/jQueryCopyToClipboard/Default.aspx).

Here's how to do it for Internet Explorer:

```
function copy (str)
{
    //for IE ONLY!
    window.clipboardData.setData('Text',str);
}
```

Comment: Is there one for firefox as well?

Comment: try this code https://stackoverflow.com/a/65474415/5295519