# Small bug when selecting text on focus

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a `input[type=text]` containing the short url for a post. i want to select the short url so users can easily copy the short url into clipboard. i used

```
$(".shorturl input").focus(function() {
    this.select();
});
```

but i noticed the 1st time it works fine then the next time it will blick (i see the text selected then deselected). it seems when like it try to select a selected text and ends up deselecting?

then to enhance this, how can i copy text to the clipboard? hopefully without flash? i see jQuery plugins to copy text but they use flash.

my site using that is http://jiewmeng.tumblr.com

Comment: The blinking seems to happen randomly. I can get the input to focus properly not just on the initial focus.

Comment: for me its alternating. 1st works, 2nd fails, 3rd works ... and so on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the `click` event instead. It seems to work when focusing on the input using the keyboard as well, but I haven't tested it cross-browser:

```
$(".shorturl input").click(function() {
    this.select();
});​
```

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/mZSyh/

For the second part of your question, see [How to copy text to the client's clipboard using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1539641/copy-text-to-the-clients-clipboard-using-jquery)

Comment: The accepted answer to that question suggests a plugin that uses Flash. Nevertheless, it works great.

Comment: Well, you can't copy text onto the clipboard with pure JavaScript, so it has to use Flash or some other plug-in.