# cross browser jquery code to copy to clipboard?

Tags: client, jquery-ui-dialog, zeroclipboard, clipboard-interaction

jquery or JavaScript code for copy content of an element to clipboard is very important as far as I think. Because I needed it for my project [here](http://webservices.x10.mx) and I spend two-three days just for it. I had done with zeroclipboard, but very inconvenient and irritating. I really think in the vast internet universe there must be a cross browser client side code to access clipboard. I hope you will suggest some thing.
     I forget to mention it was very difficult for me to link copy to clipboard code to jquery ui dialog button. Please do suggest some thing related to cross browser, jquery ui dialog button. Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Copy text to the client's clipboard using jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1539641/copy-text-to-the-clients-clipboard-using-jquery)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I copy to the clipboard in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-do-i-copy-to-the-clipboard-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2):

This question is a duplicate of [1539641](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1539641/copy-text-to-the-clients-clipboard-using-jquery) - I would be very surprised if SO didn't warn you about this since your titles are very similar.

Anyway, as stated in that earlier post, the [jQuery plugin Clipboard](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/clipboard) no longer works as it does not support Flash 10.

I would suggest you have a look at [zeroclipboard](http://code.google.com/p/zeroclipboard/). I just tested it and it works fine in the latest vers of IE, FF and Chrome.