# Is there a "copy to clipboard" function in JavaScript or jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am looking for a non-plugin "copy to clipboard" function written in jQuery or JavaScript.

Basically, I just want to click on an a link and pop the HREF value into the clipboard.

Is that possible with jQuery / JavaScript?

Comment: God, I hope not! Last thing I want is arbitrary websites messing around with _my_ clipboard.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1539641/copy-text-to-the-clients-clipboard-using-jquery or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-to-copy-to-clipboard-in-javascript

Comment: I was about to copy in my (IE only) code for doing this, but I found this StackOverflow link in my comment :-) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-to-copy-to-clipboard-in-javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it is possible with : 
http://code.google.com/p/zeroclipboard/

its from google and its via flash and js

pretty simple implementation

Comment: In mathematics, we like to say that a method is a trick (hack) that you can use more than once :-)

Comment: Doesn't this open the exact security hole that was closed by browsers not allowing "copy to clipboard" operations?  If so then see comment 1 on op.

Answer (score 1):

That is not possible with straight up javascript (in most broswers)

You might need some flash backend to do the copying.

Answer (score 1):

it's not possible due to browser's restrictions, for security reasons I believe.

I ended up using zeroClipboard, a light and practical flash plugin.