# click a link to copy visible rows into user's clipboard buffer?

Tags: jquery, clipboard

How would you copy multiple rows of data like this `<tr><td>cell 1</td><td>cell 2</td></tr>    <tr><td>cell 3</td></td>cell 4</td></tr>` into user's clipboard, ready to be pasted in Excel (one `<td>` pair will go to one cell in Excel)

I have something like this in mind:

```
$('#copy').click(function(){
   var data = $('datatable tr:visible').text();
   alert("you have copied these data: " + data + "now you can paste them in Excel");
});
```

Nothing in data variable in the alert box. Pretty much stuck here..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to paste the data in Excel, you'll probably need each row in a different line, each column separated by tabs. Example:

```
var rows = []
$('datatable tr:visible').each(function() {
    var columns = [];
    $(this).children("td").each(function() {
        columns.push($(this).text());
    });
    rows.push(columns.join("\t");
});
var data = rows.join("\n");
```

Working example at [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mgibsonbr/DXjft/5/) (adapted from OP code)

As for copying to clipboad, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1539641/520779) for more info.

**Update:** Copying from browser to clipboard is a complicated and potentially insecure operation, and AFAIK does not work consistently between browsers and operating systems. Maybe it's better to just drop the text in a `textarea`, selected, and request the user to `Ctrl+C` it. But it's up to you.

Comment: It's my first time using this fiddle: [link]http://jsfiddle.net/DXjft/2/ there is nothing happening..

Comment: 1. There's no `datatable`, just `table` (*Edit:* in the 1st fiddle, I see you fixed it in the 2nd); 2. Don't use `tr > td`, you're iterating over rows in the outer loop; 3. There's no `#testing`, and `append` is used with html, not text; 4. I believe `clipboardData` only works in IE. See [this](http://jsfiddle.net/mgibsonbr/DXjft/5/) for a closer-to-working example.

Comment: Thank you so much mgibsonbr! I corrected the silly mistake you spotted and you code rocks! I use this method for clipboard:`window.clipboardData.setData('Text',str);` I only need to make it work in IE in my situation. Thanks!