# Unselectable text in div to selectable leaflet

Tags: javascript, css, leaflet

As the title says, I used this ([Example](http://leafletjs.com/examples/choropleth))
More specifically I used the info box in top right corner(US Population Density). I modified it to show me some more info onclick etc. Now I have a problem, this div is unselectable. I need to be able to select text (for copy text purpose), instead of selecting the text, it just moves the map. Is there a "quite easy solution" to it, because I can't find the  right place. Maybe somehow in CSS?

```
.info {
        position: fixed;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 23px;   
        padding: 6px 8px;
        font: 14px/16px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        background: white;
        background: rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
        box-shadow: 0 0 15px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
        border-radius: 5px;
        /*-webkit-user-select: text;
           -moz-user-select: text;
                user-select: text;
        -webkit-user-drag: text;*/   /*Tried this, didn't work. */

    }
    .info h4 {
        margin: 0 0 100px;
        color: #777;
    }
```

Edit: I should add, when I start selecting on other div, then I can select it. As seen on picture, if I start selecting on div where my layers are shown, I can select text, but if I try to directly select from that div (on top right corner of picture) it moves map. I know picture is cut quite small, hope it gives the info/vision wha needed. 
Picture: http://www.upload.ee/image/3839164/asd.PNG

Thanks, 
Kristjan

Comment: There are event listeners on the map div, they catch mouse clicks. I can suggest 2 solutions: 
1. Js: make a button ( or on click on info div) which will copy the text to the buffer.
2. Try to disable those listeners and add the default.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1539641/how-to-copy-text-to-the-clients-clipboard-using-jquery

Answer (score 7):

Use disableClickPropagation in your controls onAdd method.

```
onAdd: function (map) {
    var container = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'my-custom-control');
    container.innerHTML += 'This is an example using disableClickPropagation.';
    L.DomEvent.disableClickPropagation(container);
    return container;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9q756/1/

Comment: This worked for me. Also I had to modify all of the CSS attributes with suffix ***-user-select: none;**

Answer (score -1):

You can fix this by re-enabling pointer-events on the bottom en top control-containers. These get set to none in leaflet.css:

https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/blob/master/dist/leaflet.css#L93

You need to overrule this in your own custom CSS:

```
.leaflet-top,
.leaflet-bottom {
    pointer-events: all;
}
```

Comment: Tried it, didn't work. I should add, when I start selecting on other div, then I can select it. As seen on picture, if I start selecting on  div where my layers are shown, I can select text, but if I try to directly select from that div (on top right corner of picture) it moves map.
I know picture is cut quite small, hope it gives the info/vision wha needed.
Picture: http://www.upload.ee/image/3839164/asd.PNG
Thank you for answering anyway.

Comment: May you could supply a JSFiddle or Plnkr?

Comment: Unfortunately no. This project contains info what i'm not allowed to share.