# How to select and copy a textarea content on click?

Tags: jquery, html, textarea

I am using this to select all content, but how do I copy it to the clipboard at the same time?

```
<textarea onfocus="this.select();" onmouseup="return false;"  name="tags" cols="50" rows="5">
```

I've tried the following code, but it didn't work out:

```
copy_sel.clipboard({
    path: 'jquery.clipboard.swf',
    copy: function() {
        var text = $('textarea#tags').val();
        alert('Text copied. Try to paste it now!asdfasdf: '+text);
        return $('textarea#tags').val();
    }
});
```

Comment: do you want to copy to clipboard or to a variable ?

Comment: try this:
[copy textarea text to clipboard][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1539641/how-to-copy-text-to-the-clients-clipboard-using-jquery

Comment: @KrishnaM clipboard (in particular on my Samsung S3, but i guess it will work as if it was in a regular desktop browser)