# Copy to clipboard with jQuery/js in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, clipboard, copy-paste

I know this kind of question has been asked here for many times, including:  [How do I copy to the clipboard in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/400212/1299675) or [How to copy text to the client's clipboard using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1539641/1299675), I'm narrowing the scope:

Condition:

1. works fine in Google Chrome (would be nice if cross-browser, but not necessary)
2. with no flash

Is there such a solution or workaround?

Comment: copying with no flash ?? what do you mean ????

Comment: @C-link using embed flash is just a overkill but really cross-browser trick:http://stackoverflow.com/a/3953655/1299675

Comment: There is a `copy` command in chrome. `let a = 'Foo Bar'; copy(a);` Then 'Foo Bar' will be in your clipboard.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I just find another amazing repo on Github.

> Modern copy to clipboard. No Flash. Just 3kb gzipped
>
> https://github.com/zenorocha/clipboard.js

Browser Support:

[image]

Comment: the thing I don't like about that library is that it just doesn't provide you a javascript function to call, I don't know if it's because of any limitation, but I don't want bootstrap like event binding as it may clash with my JS Framework (think angularJS, knockout, etc)

Comment: Simple and easy to use. Don't forget to initialize with 'new ClipboardJS('.btn')'.

Answer (score 32):

You can use either `document.execCommand('copy')` or `addEventListener('copy')`, or a combination of both.

**1. copy selection on custom event**

If you want to trigger a `copy` on some other event than `ctrl-c` or right click copy, you use `document.execCommand('copy')`. It'll copy what's currently selected. Like this, on mouseup for example:

```
elem.onmouseup = function(){
    document.execCommand('copy');
}
```

EDIT:

`document.execCommand('copy'`) is supported only by `Chrome 42`, `IE9` and `Opera 29`, but will be supported by firefox 41 (scheduled for september 2015). Note that IE will normally asks for permission to access the clipboard.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand

**2. copy custom content on copy triggered by user**

Or, you can use `addEventListener('copy')`, this will interfere with copy event and you can put the content you want there. This suppose user triggers copy.

EDIT:

On Chrome, Firefox and Safari the event has the `clipboardData` object with `setData` method. On `IE`, the `clipboardData` object is a window property. So this can work on all major browsers provided you validate where is `clipboardData`.

```
 elem2.addEventListener('copy', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (e.clipboardData) {
        e.clipboardData.setData('text/plain', 'custom content');
    } else if (window.clipboardData) {
        window.clipboardData.setData('Text', 'custom content');
    }

});
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ClipboardEvent/clipboardData
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535220(v=vs.85).aspx

**3. a bit of both**

Using a combination, you can copy custom content on wanted events. So the first event triggers `execCommand`, then the `listener` interferes. For example, put custom content on click on a div.

```
  elem3.onclick = function () {
        document.execCommand('copy');
    }

   elem3.addEventListener('copy', function (e) {

    e.preventDefault();
    if (e.clipboardData) {
        e.clipboardData.setData('text/plain', 'custom content from click');
    } else if (window.clipboardData) {
        window.clipboardData.setData('Text', 'custom content from click');
    }

});
```

Using this last one supposes that both approach are supported, as of July 2015, it works only on `Chrome 43` (maybe 42 I couldn't test) and `IE` at least 9 and 10. With `Firefox 41` supporting `execcommand('copy')`, it should work as well.

Note that for most of these methods and properties are declared as either experimental (or even deprecated for IE), so it's to be used carefully, but it looks like it's more and more supported.

Fiddle with all examples: https://jsfiddle.net/jsLfnnvy/12/

Comment: And be aware that it only works fine in Chrome 43+.   See here : https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/04/cut-and-copy-commands?hl=en

Comment: This worked for me in Chrome 80 **except** I had to hook `copy` on `document`, not on `elem3` (which in my case was an `input type="button"`). But your `elem3` (a `div`) works in the fiddle.

Answer (score 12):

If you don't mind [IE/Safari](https://caniuse.com/#search=writetext), you can use following (new) API:

```
var promise = navigator.clipboard.writeText(newClipText)
```

[Read the docs here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clipboard/writeText)

Answer (score 11):

Variable string can copy to clipboard using below js code.

```
var text = 'text to copy';
var copyFrom = $('<textarea/>');
copyFrom.css({
 position: "absolute",
 left: "-1000px",
 top: "-1000px",
});
 copyFrom.text(text);
 $('body').append(copyFrom);
 copyFrom.select();
 document.execCommand('copy');
```

Answer (score 9):

Actually for those figuring this out i got it to work in chrome based on @JulianGregoire s answer.

I rewrote the code to make it a bit better in my opinion:

```
el.onclick = function () {
    var copy = function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log('copy');
        var text = "blabla"
        if (e.clipboardData) {
            e.clipboardData.setData('text/plain', text);
        } else if (window.clipboardData) {
            window.clipboardData.setData('Text', text);
        }
    }
    window.addEventListener('copy', copy);
    document.execCommand('copy');
    window.removeEventListener('copy', copy);
}
```

Comment: Worked perfect! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Beware: I tried the exact same script of Julien Grégoire, however it wasn't triggering the oncopy event listener. The reason, I had user-select CSS for the body-tag.

So make sure you remove it, or set it to `initial` on the element the event listener is attached to.

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/faimmedia/jsLfnnvy/80/

Answer (score 0):

**If** you're using knockout, like me (for some reason I still am), you'll want to take a look at this question/answer:

[How to make KnokoutJS and ClipboardJS work together?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40333853/how-to-make-knokoutjs-and-clipboardjs-work-together/47694716#47694716)

Answer (score -6):

```
function copyToClipboard(s) {
    if (window.clipboardData && clipboardData.setData) {
        clipboardData.setData('text', s);
    }
}
```

Then call the function with the text and that should work.

Comment: This doesn't exist in latest Chrome release as of today (Chrome 39)