# Copy string to clipboard initiated by click on injected element in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Further to this question: 
[Copy to clipboard with jQuery/js in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23211018/copy-to-clipboard-with-jquery-js-in-chrome)

The code from the above question works perfectly for copying a string to clipboard with JavaScript, but I need to trigger the process from a user click onto an injected element. For some reason, the code will not work if the element is injected.

In below code example, I added a red `?` button and prepended it to the body. Note that clicking on it does not copy the desired text to clipboard. Why is that?

*<sub>(Note that I added my bit in jQuery as a personal preference)</sub>*

<kbd>[**jsFiddle demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/jsLfnnvy/157/)</kbd>

```js
var elem = document.getElementById('test');
var elem2 = document.getElementById('test2');
var elem3 = document.getElementById('test3');
elem.onmouseup = function () {
    document.execCommand('copy');
}

elem2.addEventListener('copy', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (e.clipboardData) {
        e.clipboardData.setData('text/plain', 'custom content');
    } else if (window.clipboardData) {
        window.clipboardData.setData('Text', 'custom content');
    }

});

elem3.onclick = function () {
    document.execCommand('copy');
}

elem3.addEventListener('copy', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (e.clipboardData) {
        e.clipboardData.setData('text/plain', 'bonk custom contentt');
    } else if (window.clipboardData) {
        window.clipboardData.setData('Text', 'bonkcustom content from click');
    }
});
$('body').prepend('<div id="test4" title="Click to copy text RAINBOX to clipboard">?</div>');
$(document).on('click', '#test4', function(e){
    document.execCommand('copy');
});
$(document).on('copy', '#test4', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    if (e.clipboardData) {
        e.clipboardData.setData('text/plain', 'Over the rainbox');
    } else if (window.clipboardData) {
        window.clipboardData.setData('Text', 'Rainbox');
    }
});
```

```css
#test4{display:inline-block;background-color:tomato;font-size:1.2rem;padding:0 5px;border-radius:3px;cursor:pointer;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='test'>Select text, it'll copy on mouse up</div>
<div id='test2'>Copy text using ctrl-c</div>
<div id='test3'>Click here to copy text</div>
<div id='ta'><textarea cols="40" rows="5" placeholder="Test pasting here"></textarea></div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `e.originalEvent.clipboardData` to get original event, and not jQuery event object

```js
var elem = document.getElementById('test');
var elem2 = document.getElementById('test2');
var elem3 = document.getElementById('test3');
elem.onmouseup = function () {
    document.execCommand('copy');
}

elem2.addEventListener('copy', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (e.clipboardData) {
        e.clipboardData.setData('text/plain', 'custom content');
    } else if (window.clipboardData) {
        window.clipboardData.setData('Text', 'custom content');
    }

});

elem3.onclick = function () {
    document.execCommand('copy');
}

elem3.addEventListener('copy', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (e.clipboardData) {
        e.clipboardData.setData('text/plain', 'bonk custom contentt');
    } else if (window.clipboardData) {
        window.clipboardData.setData('Text', 'bonkcustom content from click');
    }
});
$('body').prepend('<div id="test4" title="Click to copy text RAINBOX to clipboard">?</div>');
$(document).on('click', '#test4', function(e){
    document.execCommand('copy');
});
$(document).on('copy', '#test4', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    if (e.originalEvent.clipboardData) {
        e.originalEvent.clipboardData.setData('text/plain', 'Over the rainbox');
    } else if (window.clipboardData) {
        window.clipboardData.setData('Text', 'Rainbox');
    }
});
```

```css
#test4{display:inline-block;background-color:tomato;font-size:1.2rem;padding:0 5px;border-radius:3px;cursor:pointer;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='test'>Select text, it'll copy on mouse up</div>
<div id='test2'>Copy text using ctrl-c</div>
<div id='test3'>Click here to copy text</div>
<div id='ta'><textarea cols="40" rows="5" placeholder="Test pasting here"></textarea></div>
```

Comment: How did Hawkeye put it in that `M*A*S*H` episode? "For the first time, you've done it again!" - thanks guest271314, much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to `on` the event to a dynamically created element. Try this:

```
$('#test4').on("click", function() {
  //Your copy code  here
});
```

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki I tried it and it worked. Is it really that bad?

Comment: I'm sorry @webbm, I just want to say that the _bind_ method was depricated long time ago.. http://api.jquery.com/bind/

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki thanks for the information. I'll update my answer to use `on`

Comment: Note that the code in the question is already using `.on()` - thanks anyway, though