# Is it possible to copy a table format not only just the text?

Tags: jquery, html

I have a table that I output:

[image]

Is there a plugin or something that i can copy this table by clicking on a button ?

It would be something like http://zeroclipboard.org/index-v2.x.html where you can click on copy button and it will copy the html. I would think it could be done using maybe some javascript or jquery, but so far I havent been able to copy the table the way i would like just the text.

Comment: Well, there is a reason why ZeroClipboard uses Flash. But fortunately the source (on GitHub) is linked from the page you linked to, so you can just grab it and use it. So, *"is there a plugin ... "*. Yes: ZeroClipboard.

Comment: Getting the HTML for a table is as simple as getting the `.innerHTML` property of a container object (no plug-in required).  Copying to the clipboard is more of a pain in browsers, but obviously you're already aware of zeroclpboard (with the interoperability warts that it comes with).

Comment: Take a look at this [question & answer][1], i hope this help


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1539641/how-to-copy-text-to-the-clients-clipboard-using-jquery

Comment: @ragnar thanks didnt find that at first